# Ruby: each_slice, map, inject

Tags: python, ruby

I am trying to translate this bit of Ruby code to Python and I am having trouble understanding it. I understand the individual parts, but I am new to Ruby and it's confusing to me how they all fit together.

```
#input: 16 bit array
hexes = input.each_slice(4).map.inject([]) { |sum, s| sum << s.join.to_i(2)}
```

If anyone could help me decipher this, I would appreciate it greatly!
Thank you

Comment: You cannot expect a full explanation for every single step in the code you posted. You need to be more specific about which part you cannot understand.

Comment: @sawa Thank you for your response. I changed my question.

Comment: You have to be much more specific. Otherwise, the answer to your question is basically the entire Ruby Language Specification. What is it that you don't understand? The syntax? The semantics? Do you know what an `Array` is? Do you know what a method is? Do you know what a message send is? Do you know what a `String` is? Do you know what an `Integer` is? Do you know what a block is? Do you know what a comment is? Do you know how to pass arguments to message sends? Do you know how to pass arguments to blocks? Do you know what an argument is? Do you know where you can find method documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily try this by typing each step into an interactive Ruby prompt (irb).

Let's say `input` is:

```
["1", "0", "0", "1", 
 "0", "1", "0", "1", 
 "1", "0", "1", "0", 
 "0", "1", "1", "0"]
```

The `each_slice(4)` breaks it up into:

```
[["1", "0", "0", "1"], 
 ["0", "1", "0", "1"], 
 ["1", "0", "1", "0"], 
 ["0", "1", "1", "0"]]
```

In this case, the `map` is unnecessary and does nothing.

The `inject` is the same as `reduce`. You give it an initial value, and the block gets called with that and the first item of the list, and then the result of that call and the next item in the list, etc. etc.

So it gets called with:

```
[[], ["1", "0", "0", "1"]]
[[9], ["0", "1", "0", "1"]]
[[9, 5], ["1", "0", "1", "0"]]
[[9, 5, 10], ["0", "1", "1", "0"]]
```

and finally returns `[9, 5, 10, 6]`.

In Python, the closest equivalent would be very un-Pythonic:

```
reduce(
    (lambda sum, s: (sum.append(int(''.join(s), 2)) or sum))
    (input[i * 4:(i + 1) * 4] for i in range(4)),
    [])
```

So instead you could do something like:

```
slices = (input[i * 4:(i + 1) * 4] for i in range(4))
sum = [int(''.join(s), 2) for s in slices]
```

Which in Ruby would also be better:

```
input.each_slice(4).map { |s| s.join.to_i(2) }
```

Comment: In that case, the python code is: `hexes = [int(''.join(el), 2) for el in zip(*[iter(input)]*4)]`

Comment: @JonClements I'm aware of the zip / iter style of slicing, but it's pretty much unreadable. Also it's not lazy, which doesn't matter in this case, but in general is nice.

Comment: It's lazy in 3.x, replace with `itertools.izip` for 2.x - as for readability - it's an idiomatic technique that's even explained/used several times in the official documentation. I certainly have to work to grok the `reduce` shown, and it takes a moment to figure out what `slices` does, while if I see the `zip` then I immediately know what it's doing